# Generalized Method of Moments on log-normal distribution

Tags: r, statistics

I try to perform a gmm on a log-normal sample.

This is an example with a normal distribution

```
n <- 1000

x <- rnorm(n, mean = 4, sd = 2)
g <- function(tet, x)
{
  m1 <- (tet[1] - x)
  m2 <- (tet[2]^2 - (x - tet[1])^2)
  m3 <- x^3 - tet[1]*(tet[1]^2 + 3*tet[2]^2)
  f <- cbind(m1, m2, m3)
  return(f)
}
library(gmm)
gmm(g, x, c(0, 0))
```

I would like to do the same with log-normal, that's my code:

```
x<-rlnorm(1000,3,5)
g <- function(tet, x)
{
  m1 <- exp(tet[1]+1/2*(tet[2]^2)) -x
  m2 <- exp(2*tet[1]+1/2*2^2*(tet[2]^2)) -x^2
  # m2 <- (exp(tet[2]^2)-1)*(exp(tet[1]+1/2*(tet[2]^2)))^2 -x^2
   m3 <- exp(3*tet[1]+1/2*3^2*(tet[2]^2)) -x^3
   f <- cbind(m1, m2, m3)
  return(f)
}
gmm(g, x, c(0, 0))
```

but the error message is

```
Error in solve.default(w, gbar) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.968e-34
```

I use this formula : [wikipedia link for log-normal moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Arithmetic_moments)

Any idea why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

The issues arise from the empirical moment covariance matrix of the moments which is not invertible. It is necessary if you want to compute the optimal weight matrix (w). You can try:

```
gt <- g(c(0,0),x)
solve(var(gt))
```

With `seed(123)`, I have very big numbers in the covariance matrix of the moments for the log-normal estimation:

```
             m1           m2           m3
m1 1.236396e+13 8.183621e+20 6.004444e+28
m2 8.183621e+20 6.010799e+28 4.647952e+36
m3 6.004444e+28 4.647952e+36 3.702954e+44
```

Maybe it is why this matrix is not invertible.[You can read a more detailed explanation on Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78994/gradient-in-gmm-estimation?rq=1).